# How to optimize audio playback in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio, just-audio

I'm playing one audio after another in Flutter, using the following code:

```
onPressed: () {
  audioPlayer.setUrl(
      'https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar'
          '.alafasy/${state.ayahList[i-1]}.mp3');
  audioPlayer.play();

  audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((event) async {
    if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
      if (i < state.ayahList.length) {
        print(
            'ayah:${state.ayahList[i]} Length: ${state.ayahList
                .length} I: $i Hillow');
        audioPlayer.setUrl(
            'https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/${state.ayahList[i]}.mp3');
        await audioPlayer.play().then((value) => i++);

      } else {
        i = 0;
      }
    }
  });
},
```

This works, but it's a bit slow and could be optimized. I'm looking for a more efficient way to play one audio after another in Flutter. I'm using `just_audio` packege for playing audio.

Comment: Are you asking how to eliminate the gap between items? i.e. gapless playlists?

Comment: @RyanHeise Exactly

Comment: Did you read the README page? Try searching for gapless.